# Is there any way to bind an remote socket service and receive message from client in android?

Tags: android, sockets

What I'm trying to do is:

1. create a service which listens to a socket.
2. start another app which bind to that service and receive messages from the client of the socket (and possibly send something back to the client).

I have event listener callbacks for that service and returned as a Binder, but I'm not sure if aidl can handle event listeners. If not, is there any other way to achieve this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I take an alternative option: 
I create a synchronized message buffer whose writer is a callback in the socket thread, and reader is exposed in the aidl file. 
Though a litle redundant, this is the only way I can find to achieve my goal for now.

```
public class CBuffer {
    private List<String> list =
        new ArrayList<String>();

    public synchronized void add(String cmd) {
        list.add(cmd);
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized String get()
        throws InterruptedException
    {
        while (list.size() == 0)
            wait();
        return list.remove(0);
    }
}
```